# Prestashop hide a part of the product name

Tags: smarty, prestashop

I added a regex-replace at $product-name to insert a break-line in the title when there is a +. It's ok for the product list and the product.tpl

Now, I wish to hide the part of the title from the + just for the cart and the order. Is it possible with a replace and how to do ? The title must be in only one line.

THanks for your help.

Comment: Do you want to apply the same regex-replace than product list in your cart and in the order page? Have you tried and it is not displayed as you want or you don't know where to do the modification?

Answer (score 0):

You can extract this part with this:

We need to use the substr function, and obtain the first place that appear the "+" symbol, and the total lenght to the variable, you can do with this:

```
{assign var="symbol_pos" value=$product_name|strpos:"|"}
{assign var="total_char" value=$product_name|count_characters:true}

{$product_name|substr:($symbol_pos+1):$total_char}
```

*Be sure that the varialbe name is this.

Hope it helps you.